# How can I use xpath text() locater to locate an element which contain &nbsp;&nbsp;?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So I am trying to locate Account Activity from below lines of codes using contains(text(), 'value') but I am not able to do so. I tried to remove &nbsp using different stackoverflow answers but none of them work. Can someone please help me out here?

WebPage:
[image: WEbPage]

Mylines of code:

[image: Mylinesofcode]

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the error giving in the console. And have you tried with JavascriptExecutor to click the element? 
Syntax:
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `xpath`:
`//span[contains(text(),'Account Activity')]`
From the web page structure you presented here it looks like the `Account Activity` and `Current Day Balances` are not inside the `input` elements but they are all inside the `small` element which is inside `span` so I'd prefer basing on `span` element containing all them.

Comment: I think the issue is with the space and not the Xpath. I tried your Xpath and did not worked. thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Try this by normalizing the spaces:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[normalize-space(text()) = 'Account Activity']").click()
```

If that doesn't work maybe try another approach:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("irOperations[0]").click()
```

Comment: I tried normalize-space and it did not work. Thanks.